# Running virtual machines in a cgroup

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, cgroups

Is something like this possible for VirtualBox and/or VMware Workstation? And if so, which processes should be assigned to the cgroup to ensure the entire virtual machine is limited to the resources specified by the cgroup, regardless of its allocation settings.

I could see this being useful so that the idea of "cpushares" in cgroups can be abstracted to be comparable to % cpu, as defined in virtual machine configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to get the pid of VM

```
 ps axuw | grep vmware-vmx
```

and get the pid then put it into the cpu.tasks in cgroup by using 'echo'